# Fetch all rows from SQLite and pass as POST parameters

Tags: android, sqlite, android-volley

I've an `SQLite db` with 2 items. I can get first row using `HashMap` and save it in Strings to show the values. But I want to get all rows and pass them as parameters in `Volley POST Stringrequest`. To check the output of fetched result, I add the String values to `textview` but the `textview` only shows the forst row. So how to get all rows?

```css
Activity:

public class NewActivity extends Activity{
 
 TextView name, mobile;
 private SQLiteHandler db;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.newactivity);
  
  name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
  mobile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
  db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
 }
 
 public void show(View v){  //on button click
  
  HashMap<String, String> pro = db.getProfDetails();
  for( int i=0; i<pro.size();i++){
   String proName = pro.get("name"); 
   String proMobile = pro.get("mobile"); 
   name.setText(proName);
   mobile.setText(proMobile);
   
  }
  
 }

}
```

```html
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

 // All Static variables
 // Database Version
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 // Database Name
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

 // Profile Settings table name
 private static final String TABLE_PROF = "prof";

 // Profile Settings information names
 private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
 private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 private static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";


 public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 // Creating Tables
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

  String CREATE_PROF_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROF + "("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,  "+KEY_MOBILE+" TEXT" + ")";

  db.execSQL(CREATE_PROF_TABLE);

  Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
 }

 // Upgrading database
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // Drop older table if existed
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROF);

  // Create tables again
  onCreate(db);
 }


 /**
  * Storing Prof_settings details in database
  * */
 public void addProfile(String name, String mobile){

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  values.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);

  // Inserting Row
  //long id = db.update(TABLE_PROF, values, KEY_ID, null);  //for update
  //db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_PROF); //clears 1st row
  long id = db.insert(TABLE_PROF, null, values); // insert to 1st row
  db.close(); // Closing database connection

  Log.d(TAG, "New profile settings inserted into sqlite: " + id);

 }




 /**
  * Getting Profile Settings data from database
  * */
 public HashMap<String, String> getProfDetails() {
  HashMap<String, String> pro = new HashMap<String, String>();
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PROF;

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  // Move to first row
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
   pro.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
   pro.put("mobile", cursor.getString(2));
  }
  cursor.close();
  db.close();
  // return log details
  Log.d(TAG, "Fetching profile details from Sqlite: " + pro.toString());

  return pro;
 }

 /**
  * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
  * */
 public void deleteUsers() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  // Delete All Rows
  db.delete(TABLE_PROF, null, null);
  db.close();

  Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all profile info from sqlite");
 }

}
```

Comment: Show Volley related code which u have tried

Comment: Here may be the getProfDetails() method have an issue as you are trying to overwrite the latest value to HashMap please check that db method by debugging firdst.

Comment: I'm trying to check if the values are inserting. To check that, I'm fetching the values and setting them as textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the DB method to get all the records from the table :

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getProfDetails()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " + " FROM " + PROFILE_TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY " + PRFOILE_COLUMN_USERNAME + " ORDER BY " + PRFOILE_COLUMN_USERNAME + " COLLATE NOCASE;", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("name", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(PROFILE_COLUMN_USERNAME)));
            hashmap.put("mobile", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(PROFILE_COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER)));

            array_list.add(hashmap);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
```

You can get response like below :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
arrayList = databaseHandler.getProfDetails();

if (arrayList.size() != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
                {
                profilenameList.add(arrayList.get(i).get("name"));     
                profilemobilenumberlist.add(arrayList.get(i).get("mobile"));

                }
           }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm getting values but with small prob.

Comment: @Sam: what problem ?

Comment: I'm getting result with 1 blank values. http://postimg.org/image/6txwv7kz3/c6cdcb63/   . Also, how to get items as separate as I want them to add as parameters in volley stringrequest?

Comment: What's "profilenameList" here? Is it List<String>? @KishuDroid

Comment: There all are ArrayList<String>()

Comment: Thanks so much. Now its working absolutely fine. @KishuDroid

Comment: One last query. http://www.hastebin.com/xujifunudi.avrasm.  I used this code to display ArrayList to text. Can u tell me why the last entry is displaying above the first?

Answer (score 0):

Please check small Change in below code it will work:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getProfDetails()
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_PROF, null);

 if(cursor!=null)
 {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
            hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("name", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
            hashmap.put("mobile", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOBILE)));

            array_list.add(hashmap);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     } 

}
    return array_list;
}
```

You can get profile details given  below :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
arrayList = databaseHandler.getProfDetails();

if(arrayList !=null && arrayList.size()>0){
{
  //extract  the name and mobile number from arrayList 

}
```